# Craft creating dirty transparent background on image transformations / resizing

Tags: image-transforms

for anyone experiencing dirty transparent backgrounds when you transform transparent PNG images with Craft like this:

Source Image:

[image: Src Image]

Resized, dirty:

```
Craft Command: craft.assets.id(2).first().getUrl({width: 300})
```

[image: dirty image, 300px width]

If you don't see the dirt, watch screen from the side!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the GD image library. If you switch to imagick, the transparent background will be clean:

Resized, clean:

[image: clean resize]